# array_multisort with multi-dimensional object array

Tags: php, object, multidimensional-array

I want to sort a multi-dimensional array in which each array is an object. The example at

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

indicates the need to create an array of the columns on which to sort

```
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $volume[$key]  = $row['volume'];
    $edition[$key] = $row['edition'];
}

array_multisort($volume, SORT_DESC, $edition, SORT_ASC, $data);
```

but I get the followiwng error if I format my request in this format:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Code is as follows with a key/value pair for last name with key last_name:

```
foreach ($mw_users as $key => $value) {
$last_name[$key]  = $row['last_name'];
}

array_multisort($last_name, SORT_ASC, $mw_users);
```

Comment: You can't sort objects, you need to sort on a number or string.

Comment: I want to sort on one element in the object in this case the last_name

Comment: Found the answer - define an array for each column you wish to sort by and add the column values using the object reference syntax:

    foreach ($mw_users as $mw_user) {
    $lastnames[] = $mw_user->last_name;
    $firstnames[] = $mw_user->first_name;
    }

    array_multisort($lastnames, SORT_ASC, $firstnames, SORT_ASC, $mw_users);

Comment: If that works, then please post your answer in the answer section for posterity.

Comment: am not able to for another 7 hours according to stackoverflow but shall do then.

Comment: @Reverent: I thought that you could sort objects as long as they had a __toString() method?

Answer (score 2):

Define an array for each column you wish to sort by and add the column values using the object reference syntax:

```
// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($mw_users as $mw_user) {
    $lastnames[]  = $mw_user->last_name;
    $firstnames[] = $mw_user->first_name;
}

// Sort the data with volume descending, edition ascending
// Add $mw_users as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($lastnames, SORT_ASC, $firstnames, SORT_ASC, $mw_users);
```

It's similar to sorting database results: [http://php.net/...array-multisort.php...](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php#example-5130).

Answer (score 0):

When sorting arrays of objects in PHP, it helps to override __tostring() magic method. That way the various sort methods perceive the object as something comparable. For example, a staff object could output the name, or staff id of that staff member.